# How do I turn off .js for certain media queries?

Tags: javascript

I have a portfolio page that uses a lightbox .js plugin and I want to be able to turn that off when I have a screen size of less that 480 because the box pop ups are too large. Is there a way to do this in css? If not how do I go about this in .js?

This is the site http://www.campusphotoservices.org/portfolio.html

Comment: As a side note, you should scale down the images on your page in a graphics program so they don't take so long to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with CSS directly, but it's pretty simple to do with JavaScript.

In the spot in your code where you call lightbox, just check that the window's width is greater than 480px; otherwise do whatever else it is that you want to do.

```
window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can match media queries just like would in CSS. There's a matchMedia() object attached to the window, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia. You use media queries just like you would in the CSS.

```
var mediaQuery = matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)");
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  /* the view port is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the view port is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

Not all browsers support it so you'll need to use the matchMedia polyfill, https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/